# Delete all files in a directory using a bash command only if the file is a .png image file

Tags: linux, bash

Sorry for the newbish question, I would normally look up how to do this but i'm in a dire situation where any mistakes could cause large file loss so I need to be careful.

Any ideas? Preferably pre-tested ones, thanks!

Comment: `rm -f *.png`...

Comment: In `zsh`: `rm -f **/*.png` removes files recursively.

Comment: Did you consider using some version control system (like `git`) for your more serious (non-image) files?

Comment: If you are affraid to lost something, rename the files first into an another directory. You can delete them after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will assume that the files do not have an extension that corresponds to the file type (`.png` for PNG files) because otherwise the solution would be obvious.

If that's the case you can use the magic of `file`. This command will show any PNG files in the current directory and any subdirectory:

```
$ find  -exec bash -c "file -b --mime-type {} | grep -q ^image/png$" \; -print
```

And this one will delete them:

```
$ find  -exec bash -c "file -b --mime-type {} | grep -q ^image/png$" \; -delete
```

Answer (score 2):

This is actually very simple.

Just cd into your directory.

And type

```
rm *.png
```

This will automatically remove all files with the PNG extension.

And as for you being worried about losing data, just make a copy(or copies) of the directory. It is always good to have backups of important data. You never know when you might need them!

Answer (score 2):

Since you are saying it can cause large file loss, you can find the files first, just to make sure the file list is proper.

```
find YOUR_DIRECTORY -name '*.png'
```

After you have confirmed the list of files, just add `-exec`

```
find YOUR_DIRECTORY -name '*.png' -exec rm -f {} +
```

P.S: This would do a search in the sub-directories and find/delete them.

Comment: Your command will break if there are .png files in the current directory.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I use this command a lot for `grep`ing in files with specific extension.

Comment: The unquoted `*.png` gets parsed by the shell before being passed to find. If the glob matches in the shell, or if `nullglob` is enabled, your command will not work. Quotes are very important in the shell.

Comment: Yeah, a new learning. :-)